# Get uploaded image URL in Media Share message

Tags: marketing-cloud

is there any ampscript function or way to get the url of a posted image when I do an MMS Media Share message in mobile connect?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is this image hosted?  If its just in your ET portfolio, there are some functions might be able to recommend.  Otherwise, I 'll have to do some more digging.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure of a function per se, but you can click on "View Responses".  In the approvals and/or the portfolio dialogue, clicking an individual image will enlarge it and show the URL at the bottom of the screen (see screenshot).

[image: red ball example]